# Undefined property: stdClass::$**** in One to Many Relationships Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am creating a Laravel5 project where the Voters is related to a City in one to many relationships: every voter has only one City while City has many voters

My Table looks like this

//voters

```
Id Name City_id
```

//city

```
Id Name
```

And inside App/Models

//city.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
/**
*The table associated with the model
*
*/
protected $table = 'city';

/**
* indicates if the model should be timestamped
* @var bool
*/

public $timestamps = false;

 public function voters()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\Voters');
 }
}
```

voters.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Voters extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'voters';

 public function city()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
 }
}
```

I can accessed all voters in the controller this way

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class VotersController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
  public function index()
  {
     $voters = DB::table('voters')->get();
     return view('voters.all_voters',['voters' => $voters] );
  }
 }
```

But the problem is the voter's city return an error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$city (View: .....
```

The blade template

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Profession</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Province</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Island</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($voters as $voter)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $voter->firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $voter->birthday }}</td>
            <td>{{ $voter->profession_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $voters->city_id }} </td>//returnm the city_id but I want the city name in this case
            <td>{{ $voter->city->name }}</td>//
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to properly display related field for this kind of relationships in Laravel?

Update

Upon checking the property

```
 @if(isset($voter->city))
    {{ $voter->city->name }}
  @endif
```

Throws no error but the city return no values
The result shows that city is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the voter has a related city, otherwise blade will complain. We can express this in verbose PHP code like so:

```
{{ isset($voter->city) ? $voter->city : 'Default' }}
```

However, instead of writing a ternary statement, Blade provides you with the following convenient short-cut:

```
{{ $votert->name or 'Default' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the relationships. A city has many voters. And a voter belongs to a city.

In the City Model

```
 public function voters()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\models\Voters');
 }
```

In Voters Model

```
 public function city()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\models\City');
 }
```

In your controller don't use query builder instead use the model for querying.

```
  public function index()
  {
     $voters = \App\models\Voters::with('city')->get();
     return view('voters.all_voters',['voters' => $voters] );
  }
```

Comment: I tried your answer but I got this error "Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/Laravel5_1/duterte/resources/views....." inside my view I tried to access voter's city {{ voter->city->name }}.Removing this will remove error but render blank field for the voter's related city

Comment: Am assuming for all records in voters table the city_id field has a matching record in city table. Could you do dd(Voters::find(1)->city) ....to see if you get a value. and you can append ->toArray() after city to see if values match those of that city.

Comment: Yes there is a  matching record after running dd(Voters::find(1)->city.Well I almost there, I just added to protected $table='city' in my model and base on your answer, I got result in array format {"id":"1606","name":"Quezon City\t","province_id":"14","created_by":"ianrussel","date_created":"2015-07-11 09:48:23","updated_by":null,"date_updated":null}.I just need the name value in this case.In view I tried {{$voter->city}} inside @foreach loop.When I tried {{$voters->city->name}} an exception occurs."Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: It should be $voter->city->name. and not voters as per your loop

Comment: $voter->city->name returns "Trying to get property of non-object " exceptions..On the other hand, $voter->city returns "{"id":"1606","name":"Quezon City\t","province_id":"14","created_by":"ianrussel","date_created":"2015-07-11 09:48:23","updated_by":null,"date_updated":null}".

Comment: Probably there exists a voter where they are not linked to a city. Hence the loop fails at this point.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the scenario is.The problem is, this is a finished project in Symfony  and it is working, the client wants this to have two working frontend, one in symfony2, and laravel, with both using the same database.That is why, when using php isset function,the view will just render minus the 'name'  city_id field.Maybe this will be solved using if else in blade ..

Comment: I tried to delete voters where city_id is null or empty, and using the code you provided, the laravel app now is working.The remaining problem to solve is how to render this view in blade in production if some voter's city_id is empty..

Answer (score 0):

Using the code provided by user @Mwaa Joseph, I can display all voters, only if voters linked to city.But what if voter is not linked to city? Example voter's city_id is empty or null, Blade will complain

```
"Trying to get property of non-object (View:......"
```

So the solution is to add ...if.. else condition inside Blade template

```
  <td>{{$voter->city->name}}</td>//works if all voters linked to city

  //the solution
  <td>
    @if(empty($voter->city->name))
        {{$voter->city}}
    @else
        {{$voter->city->name}}
    @endif
    </td>
```